# Can't get hidraw0 device to open in nodeJS app

Tags: node-serialport

Good evening!

I'm trying to setup a barcode scanner app using the Node SerialPort package, used on a Raspberry Pi 4, and I'm having a hard time getting the code to either recognise the device

I've identified that the path is `/dev/hidraw0` as this is what I was able to ascertain from a dmesg output.

When I run `cat /dev/hidraw0` it opens and when I scan a barcode it outputs **%""'#''!'&"** to the console *(I know it's gibberish, but different problem for a different day)*. BUT, when I reference this path in my nodeJS code, I get the below error:

```
Serial port error: Error: Error: Invalid argument setting custom baud rate of 9600
```

I've confirmed on the manufacturer website that the default baud rate is 9600. I have tried removing the baudRate option in the below code, but it still says the same error.

This is the code I'm using right now:

```
// Use the serialport module to get scanner  data
const SerialPort = require('serialport');
const Readline = require('@serialport/parser-readline')

// Open the serial port with some configuration
const port = new SerialPort('/dev/hidraw0', {baudRate: 9600});
const parser = new Readline()
port.pipe(parser)

// When the port is open just say so
port.on('open', function() {
 console.log('Serial port open');
});

// Check for errors on the serial interface
port.on('error', function(err) {
 console.log(`Serial port error: ${err}`);
});

// Pass scanner data onto web server
port.on('data', function(data) {
 console.log('Scan prompted');
});
```

The USB Scanner I'm using is the Zebra LS2208 and I would love some help or guidance on what may be causing this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else comes around this, I was not able to get the device working with the NPM package I referenced, but as this module used [**node-hid**](https://github.com/node-hid/node-hid), I decided to use that one and was able to get my scanner recognised and working properly.